# Change file tab color in netbeans

Tags: macos, netbeans, ide, customization

I have search all over the interwebs for an answer to this. On Mac the files tabs text color is too light (shown below). If the file is new the problem isn't present. It is VERY hard for me to read. How can I change the text color for the file tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a theme plugin, as described here:
https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/the-complete-guide-to-tuning-the-appearance-of-netbeans#plugins
Just install the plugin and activate a theme in Tools->Options->Appearance->Look and Feel

You could also play with the setting "Same background color for files from the same project" in Tools->Options->Appearance